# C# actual DateTime - 14

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

I want to have a the DateTime 14 days ago.

In C# you only can add days...

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
DateTime daysToKeep = DateTime.Now;
daysToKeep.AddDays(-14);
```

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign the result:

```
DateTime daysToKeep = DateTime.Now; 
daysToKeep = daysToKeep.AddDays(-14);
```

The `AddDays()` method does not modify the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime daysToKeep = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
```

You need to stress some concepts here.

`DateTime` Objects (Like `String`) are **immutable**, **you can't change them**. So their methods return new Objects and not change the object itself.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx):

> When working with the DateTime structure, be aware that a DateTime
>   type is an immutable value. Therefore, methods such as AddDays
>   retrieve a new DateTime value instead of incrementing an existing
>   value. The following example illustrates how to increment a DateTime
>   type by a day using the statement dt = dt.AddDays(1).